# Saving information using Serializable

Tags: java, swing, java-io, serializable

I am attempting to get my program to save the data inputted by a user.  Currently, I am getting a:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.awt.image.BufferedImage error
```

Now, what I have done is implement the FileWriter in my user interface class, and by examining the text file it appears it is trying to save all of the information about the text boxes and labels that I have implemented on my UI.  In my main class that my UI is based off of, there is an ArrayList which holds the objects of my project.  I need to serialize these objects but they contain a BufferedImage.  I think I have found a way to work around the BufferedImage error, but I do not want the entire UI to be serialized.

So my question is, should I move the serialization method into the class that contains my ArrayList of objects, so that the UI will not be serialized?

Comment: Frankly, you should avoid serialising objects. Serialisation is only meant for the short term (mins) storage of objects, normally for transmission to other JVMs. Instead, you should using something like XML, possibly JAXB

Comment: You can control what you serialize, as implied by @Andrew. You can also use 'transients' as it fits.

Comment: @MadProgrammer If I should avoid serializing objects, then how would you suggest I write my information into an xml? and what exactly is JAXB?

Comment: JAXB is a bindings API to bind object properties to XML nodes. Checkout [this](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark BufferedImage fields with `transient` keyword which indicates that a field should not be serialized.

```
class A {
    transient BufferedImage bufferedImage;
    ...
```

then you can customize serialization by implementing the following methods in class A

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s) throws java.io.IOException{
    s.defaultWriteObject();
    // extract bytes from bufferedImage and write them
    ...

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s) throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    s.defaultReadObject();
    // read bytes and re-create bufferedImage
    ...
```

Comment: So, I make the BufferedImage transient, then could i parse the image into a byte array, and store that?

Comment: Yes, you can, you need to find a good example how to customize serialization

Comment: I think i found a good example located here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058663/how-to-serialize-an-object-that-includes-bufferedimages)

Comment: I've spent time on adding customization for nothing :). Looks very much like mine though

Comment: ok, cool.  Im still a little shakey on how the loading of the serialization will populate my objects information.  Guess I have a lot of reading ahead of me :/

Answer (score 1):

> ..should I move the serialization method .. so that the UI will not be serialized?

Yes.  Only the things that specifically need serializing, should be serialized.

Comment: ok, then I should move it into the class that contains my ArrayList, as I only want to serialize that.