# Correct way to send BufferedImage in object with serialization. writeObject readObject

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I'm trying to send an object with a BufferedImage through a socket. I now realize that I have to make that it transient, the class implement serializable, and override the writeObject and readObject methods. I think my write is correct but my read I keeps giving my an EOFException. Here is my class:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out)throws IOException{
    out.defaultWriteObject();
    //write buff with imageIO to out
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    in.defaultReadObject();
    //read buff with imageIO from in
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);

   int len = dis.readInt();

    byte[] data = new byte[len];
    dis.readFully(data);
    dis.close();
    in.close();

    InputStream ian = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    image= ImageIO.read(ian);
}
```

I think readInt() in readObject is throwing it.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: @Turing85 strangely enough it's not giving me a stack trace. Eclipse says source not found when I click on it

Comment: i'm fairly sure it is the readInt() though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your writeObject never writes to out. It writes to the ByteArrayOutputStream  which is not used later

UPDATE
See e.g. the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058663/how-to-serialize-an-object-that-includes-bufferedimages) how list of images is serialized. You can skip the count writing/reading

Comment: would ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", out); do the job? I'm sorry not too familiar with sockets yet.

Comment: finally the image bytes should be written to out. I think writing to out directly is ok but you can try

Comment: how would I get the image bytes? and write it to out exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are reading things that haven't been written. If you expect to read an int, you need to *write* an int. Instead you are dumping the image to a byte array out out stream, which has zero effect on the serialization whatsoever.

Your code doesn't make sense.

If you write an *image,* write it to the *object stream,* and read it back the same way, with `ImageIO.`

NB If you are getting an exception there is certainly a stack trace somewhere.